# Dedicated route in .NET Core not recognized producing 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, routes

I'm using a health checkup strategy that returns a certaing pong while I ping on the following URL.

> localhost/util/ping

This works as supposed to. Then, I was considering that a lazy user might miss to type in *util* or pehaps get confused typing *util**s***, *util**ity*** or *util**ities***. That can be frustrating, especially for new developers, who don't know of Swagger.

> localhost/ping

So I decided to introduce a dedicated pseudo route only containing *ping* aiming at the URL above. There are no other routes (except the default one) nor controllers with the name that would collide, as far I can see.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "ping",
    pattern: "ping",
    defaults: new { controller = "util", action = "ping" });
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Regrettably, the above code doesn't seem to work. It produces status code 404 and I can't see what I'm missing that could differ from [the example in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#multiple-conventional-routes).

The controller is declared as follows.

```
namespace Api.Controllers
{
  [ApiController]
  [Route("[controller]")]
  public class UtilController : ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet("ping")]
    public ActionResult Ping() { return Ok("pong"); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **override** it with a tilde `(~)` for your own particular method. In this manner, the routing mechanism also responds for any other method with the common route.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UtilController : ControllerBase {

    [HttpGet("~/[action]")]// http://localhost:5000/ping
    public ActionResult Ping() {
        return Ok("pong");
    }
    
    [HttpGet("[action]")]// http://localhost:5000/util/ping2 
    public ActionResult Ping2() {
        return Ok("pong2");
    }
}
```

[image: postman test result]

Even more apparent is to shove both paths on the same method.

```
[ApiController, Route("[controller]")]
public class UtilController : ControllerBase {

  [HttpGet("ping"), HttpGet("/ping")]
  public ActionResult Ping3() {
    return Ok("pong");
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm going to try it out right away. If it works, that's great, because then in the *Startup.cs* I only need to configure the endpoints by the default method *MapControllers()* as config.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This prefix not need anything else. I tested with the default method just a few minutes ago.

Comment: I'll take the liberty to edit your answer a bit to make it more apparent (at least to me) how the computer can be tricked into using both the full path and the convenience one on the same method. I also noticed that the snakey (wavey, tilde, ~, whatever we call it) is unnecessary there. Doesn't hurt but I seem to get the same result without it. What do you think - am I missing some special case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "ping",
    pattern: "ping",
    defaults: new { controller = "util", action = "ping" });
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=util}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Based on what i see in the example on microsoft doc that you provided, the pattern for the default route has to have `{controller=/*something*/}`, not just `{controller}`.
In my own app, i have :

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=/*myaction*/}/{id?}");
```

And my controller is HomeController.cs
That way i don't have to have `[Route("[controller]")]` at the beginning of my controller's class. However if you want to keep it, than maybe you should try:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Default",
                    pattern: "controller/{action=/*myaction*/}/{id?}");
```

Hope it helps your situation!

Comment: Not entirely sure if I was clear. There are **two** controllers. The second one that you explicitly map to *Home* mustn't be that way if the mapping's supposed to be general slug covering all the possible controllers. You'd have to explicitly map up all the controllers individually, which seems like a lot of needless coding. Also, the second mapping works as supposed to. It's the first one that fails. Have you actually made it work while working with two separate controllers?